QGIS SMART MAP Plugin error
I am having a problem using the QGIS plugin called SMART MAP. My QGIS version is 3.36-2, and it shows the Python version as 3.12.3.
Since I need to use Kriging in QGIS, I installed the SMART MAP Plugin (version 1.4, the newest). However, I can't even get it to launch. An error has occurred below:

Couldn't load plugin 'Smart_Map' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build'
___________________________________________________________________________ Contents of C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\site-packages\sklearn_check_build: setup.py                  check_build.cp37-win_amd64.pyd__init.py pycache ___________________________________________________________________________ It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly. If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget to build the package before using it: run python setup.py install or make in the source directory. If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your Python version, your operating system and your platform.

How can I fix this?

Have you checked bug reports for the plugin an got into contact with the provider?

it is already listed https://github.com/gustavowillam/SmartMapPlugin/issues/72
